# How to install client certificates globally for Google Chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: tls, certificates, chrome, ubuntu

I am trying to install a client certificate to Google Chrome running on Ubuntu. I want any user who logs in to Ubuntu to be able to use this client certificate in Chrome.

Even better if I can create a Chrome policy to force all users to use this client certificate but that is not really important.

Comment: Do you want to install a client certificate which would be used for authenticating to the server or a server certificate so that the client browser would trust the server?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to get a separate certificate for each client to provide audit capabilities. Otherwise, you won't be able to audit certificate usage.

Comment: I need a client certificate that the server will use for authenticating. However, the server does not care about the user at the workstation. It only cares about what workstation the user is at.